# Are there any alternate mirrors for downloading Android Source

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

Presently I am trying to download the android 4.0 source from

```
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-4.0.1_r1
```

The package and project paths are accessible here `https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest/+/c4e4db1a85b9bea00b9fe8c6a18f9d3357adab0c/default.xml`

Currently I am using ubuntu based curl , gitcore and repo to download the source.

I tried to search but could not find any public HTTP or FTP mirrors that shares the entire source code in a compressed iso or rar file. Is anyone aware of such public mirrors.

Comment: Well such mirrors would defeat the purpose of using git - version control.

Comment: True , I do lose version control but for now I am looking for just having a local build and at the same time share the entire source code in a portable iso or zipped format across the lab network.

Comment: I don't think this is within the scope of our site - it's not an end-user question about Android devices. You could try [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) but first I would search to see if this has been discussed (one possible example: [Is there a working public mirror of android.git.kernel.org](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7311858/is-there-a-working-public-mirror-of-android-git-kernel-org)).

Comment: Thanks @eldarerathis. I did see the question on stackoverflow however it did not provided on any open HTTP or FTP based compressed download. Anyways, thanks for your efforts and my apologies if this question went out of end user latitude and I did found one mirror to be precise :http://fosbase.com/android/

Comment: you wouldn't regret downloading the version-controlled version; it's unlikely you would never want to update it in the future, and updating the git tree is much, much faster than redownloading the whole thing again every time.

Answer (score 2):

Here are the mirrors I know of. GitHub I know is an "up to date" mirror, not sure about the rest.

- [GitHub](https://github.com/android)
- [Code Aurora](https://www.codeaurora.org/gitweb/quic/la/)

Comment: Code Aurora (CAF) is slightly tweaked for qualcomm devices... you need the `aosp/....` branch and manifest to get at the pure AOSP sources.

Comment: Can I ftp to github and download entire folder at one go ?

Comment: @MossFarmer: You can download a [zipped archive](http://i.stack.imgur.com/fvUrG.png)

Comment: @Ryan : Thanks for the link , but its a package level zipped download and not the entire branch for a particular version for example (all projects under - 4.0.1_r1)